# ImageJ - Trigger event when frame in ImageStack is changed

Tags: java, imagej

I'm trying to make an ImageJ plugin that generates a stack of masks based on a selection in each frame in an active stack.

To do that, I need to clear the mask and save it when the frame in the stack changed. I don't see any event options available on the API for ImageStack; how would I trigger a sequence of steps when the stack frame is changed? Is there an event to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event options are implemented in the `ImagePlus` class, not in the `ImageStack`.

Your plugin should implement the [`ImageListener`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/ImageListener.html) interface. In its `imageUpdated()` method, you should be able to get the current slice number and react accordingly.

Use the static method `ImagePlus.addImageListener(this)` to add your plugin as an `ImageListener`.