# How to draw the subtitle that is in the ImageJ window

Tags: java, user-interface, imagej

I have made my own customized GUI where it displays images that are opened and read by ImageJ. I am able to display the images but I can't display the subtitle that is displayed in the ImageJ window before the image.

[image: Subtitle of image]

This is what I have been trying but it doesn't seem to display anything. Is there something simple that I am missing?

```
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
ImageCanvas ic = new ImageCanvas(image);
StackWindow sw = new StackWindow(image,ic); 
Insets insets = sw.getInsets();
BufferedImage bi = image.getBufferedImage();
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)bi.getGraphics();
//g.drawImage(image.getBufferedImage(), 0, 0, null);
 g.drawString(sw.createSubtitle(), insets.left+5, insets.top+10);
 //image.draw();
sw.drawInfo(g);
panel2.add(sw.getContentPane());
frame.add(panel2);
```

Comment: Have you tried calling createUbTitle on the StackWindow?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes I have tried calling sw.createsubtitle() and I put it in a JLabel and it does display it but the problem is that when you flip through images using the scrollbar it doesn't update the subtitle. So if you are on 1/105 and you go to the 3rd image then the subtitle should be updated to 3/105 but it doesn't get updated. So thats why I tried using the paint or draw component.

Comment: @selena related - [trigger event when frame in imagestack is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21791105/imagej-trigger-event-when-frame-in-imagestack-is-changed).